# Why do I feel my schoolbag to be heavier after meals?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, psychology

I am not sure this is related to psychology or not.

My friend casually commented to me that he feels his bag to be heavier after his meal. So I started observing my perception of weight of school bag after every meal. I did this for 3 weeks ( 1 log per day i.e. lunch, 5 days a week, 15 observations).

For 15 observations, 13 times I felt my bag to be heavier. These 13 times I had regular class after lunch. The other 2 times, I had an exam an hour later my lunch.

Is it psychological and / or body function related ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could certainly be physiological. After eating more blood is diverted towards the smooth muscles around organs for digestion. This will mean your skeletel muscles have decreased blood flow so less nutrients such as Glucose available to make contractions. As you have less energy available to contract the skeletal mucles you're more than likely to feel slightly weaker.

On the contrary it may he purely psychological! :) Good question though!